# Indy TIdCmdTCPServer reading garbage

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm implementing a very simple `TIdCmdTCPServer` for receiving data from a cell phone application we also wrote. The cell application starts with a simple **hello** command, but the `OnBeforeCommandHandler` comes with garbage.

`AData` equals `'somerandomchars hello'`

The random chars are non ASCII ones.

I'm using Delphi 2007 with the bundled Indy 10.1.5 components. I've tried this:

- Maybe my program was creating some corruption so I made a very simple
  one with just a Form and a `TIdCmdTCPServer`. Same result.
- Are the Delphi 2007 Indy components buggy? I switched to Delphi 10.3. Same problem.
- Is my computer somehow corrupting the communication? I ran the simple program in other Windows 10, both physical and virtual. Got the same problem.
- Maybe the cell application was sending wrong data. Tried using Putty to send the commands directly. No luck.
- Different port? Same

I've searched for this problem but found not a single page. In fact, they all state running a `TIdCmdTCPServer` smoothly.

The most strange point is that after five or six commands, the data reads fine. On each event, the random chars are distinct from the previous one. After stepping through Indy code, I discovered that when it is about to read **the very first** time, it already has the random chars in the input buffer. Different "commands" need a different amount of cycles to begin reading without garbage. In the case of "hello", eight or nine times (not always the same).

What is causing this? I'm just starting the server with:

```
IdCmdTCPServer1.Active := True;
```

Does it need a separate thread? Indy's help doesn't say anything about that. No properties have been changed from the default ones.

Here is the code of the simple application:

```
unit test;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer,
  IdCmdTCPServer, IdCommandHandlers, IdContext, IdServerIOHandler,
  IdServerIOHandlerSocket, IdServerIOHandlerStack;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cmdsMain: TIdCmdTCPServer;
    ioshMain: TIdServerIOHandlerStack;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cmdsMainCommandHandlers0Command(ASender: TIdCommand);
    procedure cmdsMainBeforeCommandHandler(ASender: TIdCmdTCPServer;
      var AData: string; AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.cmdsMainBeforeCommandHandler(ASender: TIdCmdTCPServer;
  var AData: string; AContext: TIdContext);
begin
// here comes the garbagge
end;

procedure TForm1.cmdsMainCommandHandlers0Command(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
//
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
cmdsMain.Active := True
end;

end.
```

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object cmdsMain: TIdCmdTCPServer
    Bindings = <
      item
        IP = '0.0.0.0'
        Port = 55
      end>
    DefaultPort = 55
    IOHandler = ioshMain
    CommandHandlers = <
      item
        CmdDelimiter = ' '
        Command = 'hello'
        Disconnect = False
        Name = 'TIdCommandHandler0'
        NormalReply.Code = '200'
        ParamDelimiter = ' '
        ParseParams = True
        Tag = 0
        OnCommand = cmdsMainCommandHandlers0Command
      end>
    ExceptionReply.Code = '500'
    ExceptionReply.Text.Strings = (
      'Unknown Internal Error')
    Greeting.Code = '200'
    Greeting.Text.Strings = (
      'Welcome')
    HelpReply.Code = '100'
    HelpReply.Text.Strings = (
      'Help follows')
    MaxConnectionReply.Code = '300'
    MaxConnectionReply.Text.Strings = (
      'Too many connections. Try again later.')
    ReplyTexts = <>
    ReplyUnknownCommand.Code = '400'
    ReplyUnknownCommand.Text.Strings = (
      'Unknown Command')
    OnBeforeCommandHandler = cmdsMainBeforeCommandHandler
    Left = 312
    Top = 152
  end
  object ioshMain: TIdServerIOHandlerStack
    Left = 376
    Top = 168
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**: We modified the cell app to just send the commands to an echo server: tcpbin.com. The echo was received fine. We emulated the cell to the same server using Putty just to ensure that it was generating any garbage. In both, it ran fine.

Comment: 10.1.5 is a very old version of Indy. The current version is 10.6.2. But even so, you shouldn't be having this problem if you have coded both parties correctly. But without seeing your client code as well, there is really no way to diagnose the culprit. Are you using SSL/TLS on the client side, perhaps? Your server side isn't. And there is simply no way the server's input buffer can contain any data before its 1st read. And no, you don't need to write a thread, TIdCmdTCPServer is already threaded. Your server has a greeting setup, is the client able to receive that before sending its hello?

Comment: Hi Remmy. A few comments about your comments :D  
Both 10.1.5 (Delphi 2007) and 10.6.2 (Delphi 10.3) show the same behavior  
The client code as for today, just sends "hello" and nothing else  
No SSL/TLS is used  
I´m completely, positively and absolutely sure that when the TIdCmdTCPServer component enters Readln the are already chars in the input buffer. The buffer size contains a zero distinct value, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question, would I?  
The greeting is received fine by both our cell app and Putty

Comment: the fact that you can reproduce the issue across multiple Indy versions and multiple server machines tells me the problem is likely not with the server at all, but with the client. For instance, if you are using Putty in telnet mode instead of raw mode. But since you get this with your cell app too, I need to see the code. What do the "random chars" actually look like? Also, despite your claim, there is simply no way the server's input buffer can have data in it before the 1st read. It is physically impossible. Either your debugging is flawed, or something else is going on.

Comment: Remy, your last comment pointed me in the right direction. Problem solved. Please post it as an answer to accept it. I didn't know that RAW and Telnet modes were different. I tried talking to the application in raw mode and everything ran fine. I didn't wrote the whole cell app but I was pretty sure it used raw mode (since I thought they were the same). It was using Telnet, so after a few keystrokes to use raw it ran fine. The random chars were not random at all but IAC bytes (correctly) sent by Putty after receiving the greeting message

Comment: I have posted an answer. And FYI, Indy does have a `TIdTelnetServer` component. Though, it is not nearly as comprehensive as `TIdCmdTCPServer`, you would have to implement much of the Telnet protocol manually in its `OnNegotiate` and `OnExecute` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you can reproduce the issue across multiple Indy versions and multiple server machines tells me the problem is likely not with the server at all, but with the client. For instance, if you are using Putty in telnet mode instead of raw mode.

Comment: I will stick to TIdCmdTCPServer Remy but will also check that the cell app uses raw writing